# Errors when trying to jump to another page

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to jump from `MainActivity.java` to `ToDoList.java` by clicking the `button01` in `activity_main.xml`. I got the LogCat like this:

```
07-06 00:50:04.487: W/dalvikvm(779): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
07-06 00:50:04.516: E/AndroidRuntime(779): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-06 00:50:04.516: E/AndroidRuntime(779): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.example.splashscreen.ToDoList }
07-06 00:50:04.516: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1622)
07-06 00:50:04.516: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
07-06 00:50:04.516: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)
07-06 00:50:04.516: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331)
07-06 00:50:04.516: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3566)
07-06 00:50:04.516: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3534)
07-06 00:50:04.516: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at com.example.splashscreen.MainActivity.button1Click(MainActivity.java:39)
07-06 00:50:04.516: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at com.example.splashscreen.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:49)
07-06 00:50:04.516: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
07-06 00:50:04.516: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
07-06 00:50:04.516: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
07-06 00:50:04.516: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-06 00:50:04.516: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-06 00:50:04.516: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-06 00:50:04.516: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-06 00:50:04.516: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-06 00:50:04.516: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-06 00:50:04.516: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-06 00:50:04.516: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The code in my MainActivity.java is like this:

```
package com.example.splashscreen;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{


Button button1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

private void button1Click()
{
    startActivity(new Intent("com.example.splashscreen.ToDoList"));
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.Button01:
        button1Click();
        break;
    }
}
}
```

My Manifest is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.splashscreen"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.splashscreen.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="SplashScreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.splashscreen.ToDoList"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="goToToDoList">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.splashscreen.ToDoList"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

And the code for the button is:

```
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/Button01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:minWidth="300dp"

    android:text="To Do List" />
```

The splash screen is working fine, but when I click the button it always says it unfortunately stopped. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try this way ,

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/Button01"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="To Do List"
android:onClick="Button_Click"
android:clickable="true" />
```

Now in your Java Class

```
 public void Button_Click(View i)
    {
 Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),YOUR_CLASS_NAME.class);
startActivity(intent);

    }
```

Comment: it says void is an invalid type for the variable Button_Click

Answer (score 0):

there are two intents in your manifest file. try deleting the intent in the goToToDolist activity.

Answer (score 0):

In your *button1Click* method, try changing the following:

```
startActivity(new Intent("com.example.splashscreen.ToDoList"));
```

to:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, com.example.splashscreen.ToDoList.class));
```

The reason this happens, is because according to the [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent%28java.lang.String%29) documentation, the way you are trying to create an intent is wrong. You give a package location, but it expects an action.

Comment: still says unfortunately stopped

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{


Button button1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample);

    button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ToDoList.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

}


}
```

i hope it helps.

Comment: activity_sample has red line, i change to activity_main, but still unfortunately stopped =(